# golang mysql do not replace placeholder

Tags: mysql, go

I am using sqlx for with mysql driver, but when I execute an insert statement I got "Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

```
import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)
func main(){
db, _ := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "connetionStr")
query := fmt.Sprintf("insert into bot(poster_id,name,welcome_msg,exit_msg) values(?,?,\"%s\",\"%s\")", "hello", "bye")
result := db.MustExec(query, 1, "bot_name")

}
```

The syntax is certainly not wrong there. The problem is with the db.MustExec function. Why is it not replacing the ? place holder

Comment: Strings are single quoted in MySQL by default, not double quoted.

Comment: What are you doing there? What's the point of Sprintf with two constant string arguments? Why don't you just pass the values with placeholders, like the other two values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```golang
query := fmt.Sprintf("insert into bot(poster_id,name,welcome_msg,exit_msg) values(?,?,'%s','%s')", "hello", "bye")
result := db.MustExec(query, 1, "bot_name")
```